# Issue displaying count results in WebApi call

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure that return a record count in SQL based on certain criteria. I am trying to retrieve this count in EF Core 3 so I can pass it into an angular app. When I test the SP in SQL it returns the expected result. In the controller I configured an action route to call the SP

```
    [Route ("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCountOverdueLowPriorityWorkOrders()
    {
         var GetCountOverdueLowPriorityWorkOrders = await _repo.GetCountOverdueLowPriorityWorkOrders();

        return Ok(GetCountOverdueLowPriorityWorkOrders);
    }
```

When I test this call from Postman, I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'ID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

I am fairly new to programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the SQL procedure

 SELECT COUNT(Id)
 FROM Workorders
 WHERE Severity = 1
 AND Due < CAST(Current_TimeStamp AS DATE)

Answer (score 0):

The column containing the values for `COUNT(id)` needs to be aliased as `id`.

Try this

`SELECT COUNT(id) as ID FROM Workorders WHERE Severity = 1 AND Due < CAST(Current_TimeStamp AS DATE)`